# Castle windsor chained dependency with multiple implementations of interface in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, castle-windsor

I have a setup that looks like this:

Controller > IService > IUnitOfWork > IContext > IConnectionStringHelper

In almost all cases I want IConnectionStringHelper to be resolved by ConnectionStringHelper, but when i use *ISpecialService*, I want to use *SpecialConnectionStringHelper* as the resolver.

I use a IExceptionFilter to log and redirect the user by implementing the *OnException*, and in this method I resolve ISpecialService. This is a hook to catch all unhandled exceptions that might occur.

What happens is that I call a controller and that controller gets everything injected as it should. If an error occures, the OnException method gets called and in this method i try to resolve my SpecialService

```
var spc = WindsorConfig._windsorContainer.Resolve<ISpecialService>();
int? errandId = spc.CreateErrandFromError(message, innerMessage, StackTrace);
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I now resolve the ISpecialService, the chain is already resolved but with the wrong implementation of IConnectionStringHelper. I have tried to use the **DependsOn** but I'm not sure how to make the **IConnectionStringHelper** depend on **IService** (ISpecialService). I have tried some variations and latest I tried was this

```
Component.For<IConnectionStringHelper>().ImplementedBy<ConnectionStringHelper>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
Component.For<IConnectionStringHelper>().ImplementedBy<SpecialConnectionStringHelper>().LifeStyle.Transient,
Component.For<ISpecialService>().ImplementedBy<SpecialService>().LifeStyle.Transient
   .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>())
   .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IContext, Context>())
   .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IConnectionStringHelper, SpecialConnectionStringHelper>())
```

As the **ISpecialService** doesn't have the **IConnectionStringHelper** as a directly injected interface, I can see how this setup might not work, but is it possible, and how can I achieve it?